# Android:appear and disappear seek bar

Tags: android

How i can appear and disappear a seekbar?

I want, when the activity starts seekbar will be dissapeared but when user put his/her finger on the place where is the seekbar, the seekbar appears and user can to interactive with it, and when he finished seekbar disappears again.

Sorry about my bad english!!

Answer (score 1):

Seek bar is the part of the view class in android . so u can do

```
 seekbarObj.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)//for the visible seekbar 

 seekbarObj.setVisibility(View.GONE) // for the disappear it
```

Comment: Because i have  a custom class for vertical seekbar, can you tell me how i can implement the "setvisivilite(View.GONE)" method?Thanks!!

Comment: Seekbar b = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE); // for the disappear it 
b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// to visible  the seekbar

Comment: Yes, but as tell you above i don't use the native seekbar, i have custom, "VerticalSeekBar", and i ask you ,if you know ,how i can implement this method in my class.Thanks.

Comment: dont matter you have used your custom seekbar its one kind of the view so ,  u can handle your view i've show you